# Data wrangling in js: Calculate cumulative count and add missing consecutive dates in javascript

Tags: javascript, arrays, data-wrangling

I have an array of objects with the following structure:

```
var data = [
{date: 2020-01-01, value: 1},
{date: 2020-01-03, value: 2},
{date: 2020-01-04, value: 2},
{date: 2020-01-07, value: 8}
]
```

How can I calculate a cumulative count and add the missing dates in between using javascript? I would like to get the following result:

```
var data = [
{date: 2020-01-01, value: 1, cumulativeValue: 1},
{date: 2020-01-02, value: 0, cumulativeValue: 1},
{date: 2020-01-03, value: 2, cumulativeValue: 3},
{date: 2020-01-04, value: 2, cumulativeValue: 5},
{date: 2020-01-05, value: 0, cumulativeValue: 5},
{date: 2020-01-06, value: 0, cumulativeValue: 5},
{date: 2020-01-07, value: 8, cumulativeValue: 13}
]
```

I started mapping the data and including the index to loop over the dates but I am unsure about what's the best way to go after that:

```
data.map((d,i) => {

  return {
  

  }

})
```

Comment: The cumulative value part is easy. Would the list ever include different months or different years? That complicates things a bit.

Comment: You have two data structure mutations and they should be thought of separately. First add the missing dates and second calculate the cumulative value. It will save you hassle down the road.

Comment: Yes, the list may include different months and years. I guess it is a question of calculating the max and min date, right?

Comment: That would be one approach, then determine if every _date_ exists or not.

Comment: It will be a bit messy and not very performant. Is there a possibility of filling the date gaps at the source for performance reasons?

Comment: Likely the best approach: 1. get start and end dates (presumably first and last elements). 2. Create a new object enumerating every date 3. Look up each `date` in `data` to add `value` to new object 4. during step three calculate `cummulativeValue`.

Comment: That's how I am getting the data so I cannot fill the gaps in the source. Ok, I will try that. What's the best way to calculate the `cumulativeValue`?

Comment: You'll add both `value` and `cumulativeValue` to the new object at the same time. As you add the `value` property to the new object add its value to the running total and then add the `cumulativeValue` to the object with that total.